# Clarification about generics and S4 method dispatching in different environments in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo, r-s4

I would like to use Zoo's `index` function, while also making `index` generic and having a custom version when passing in a particular S4 object of mine. At the moment, when I call `index` on my S4 object within another function built as part of my package, it's fine - my custom `index` method is dispatched to. But when I try to use `index` on my S4 object in the console, it is dispatched to the zoo version.

So say I have a package "someTest", with one R file, containing this:

```
setOldClass("xts")

TimeSeries = setClass("TimeSeries",slots=c(
    ts = "xts"
))

setGeneric("index")

setMethod("index","TimeSeries",
      function(x,...) {
          7
      })

func = function(ob) {
    index(ob)
}
```

The NAMESPACE file includes the line:

```
importFrom(zoo,index)
```

The DESCRIPTION file includes the lines:

```
Imports:
    zoo,
    xts
```

I built the package. I'm now in the console and do:

```
> library(zoo);library(xts);library(someTest)
> example = xts(1,order.by=as.Date("2013-01-01"))
> timeSeriesExample = new("TimeSeries",ts=example)
> index(example)
  [1] "2013-01-01"
> index(timeSeriesExample) # A
  [1] 1
> func(timeSeriesExample)
  [1] 7
> someTest::index(timeSeriesExample)
  [1] 7
```

I was expecting the line marked "A" to also output 7 - i.e. to have been dispatched to my `index` method. But instead it seems to be going to Zoo's `index` method.

Based on what I thought would happen, and what actually happened, could someone please explain to me what is actually happening here and what my misunderstanding is about either S4 generics / methods and environments? And in addition, what do I need to change to make line "A" also output 7?

Many thanks!!

Patrick